# How to place a file on salt master via salt-api

Tags: salt-stack

I want to place a file a file on salt-master via salt-api. I have configured salt-api using rest cherrypy and configured a custom hook for it. I wanted to explore the use-case where we can transfer the file first to salt-master and secondly distribute it to minions. I'm able to achieve the second part but not been able to post data file to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using file.write execution module.

First login and save the token to a cookie file (I had to change eauth to ldap, auto didn't work for some reason):

```
curl -sSk http://localhost:8000/login \
      -c ~/cookies.txt \
      -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \
      -d username=USERNAME\
      -d password=PASSWORD \
      -d eauth=auto
```

Now run a job to create a file on the salt-master (assuming your salt-master is also running a salt-minion):

```
curl -sSk http://localhost:8000 \
      -b ~/cookies.txt \
      -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \
      -d client=local \
      -d tgt='saltmaster' \
      -d fun=file.write \
      -d arg='/tmp/somefile.txt' \
      -d arg='This is some example text

with newlines

A
B
C'
```

Note that the spacing used in your command will affect how the lines will show up in the file, with the example above is gives the most aesthetically pleasing result.